# How to Load Azure Data Factory Pipeline Details to Azure Blob Storage for Tracking Purpose?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell, azure-data-factory

Can anyone suggest, how to load Pipeline details to Azure Blob Storage?

For Example, I want to load a pipeline details to Master File(Info. like Pipeline Name, Pipeline Activities, Data factory Name., so on) and Child File (Info. like Pipeline Id, Activity Details with Transformation Level, Created date., so on).

I've tried with Azure PowerShell

> Get-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline

but it gives Master level data, but I need to load these data into Azure blob storage, as well as I need to update the file whenever new pipeline and delete pipeline has been happened.

I tried this approach from Azure Powershell, I am getting error while run.

```
Get-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline -ResourceGroupName "<ResourceGroupName>" -DataFactoryName "<DFName>" | Export-Csv "$Env:temp/AutomationFile.csv"
$Context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName "<StorageAccountName>" -StorageAccountKey "<StorageAccountKey>"
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Context $Context -Container "111" -File "$Env:temp/AutomationFile.csv" -Blob "SavedFile.csv"
```

Error like:

> Export-Csv: Access to the path '/AutomationFile.csv' is denied.

Please help me on this request.

Comment: So there are three questions here, I think you need to focus on one only. Or you can ask them in different posts.

Comment: Not really an answer but try calling the API directly maybe you'll have some luck - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines @arvind